# How to change object type to integer

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, dtype

I have a data frame of the following data type 'object', 'float', 'integer' the object type is alphanumeric and I want to convert all of them to an integer data frame here's my log

```
amazon = pd.read_csv('ratings_Electronics.csv',
                 encoding = 'latin-1', names=['userID','ProductID',
                                              'Ratings','Timestamp'])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
training_set, test_set = train_test_split(amazon, random_state=42,test_size=0.2)

training_set['userID'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

Here's the error log

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A77RBOGEVJ0LH'
```

Please I need someone to help me through it. Thanks

Comment: you cant convert letters to int type because it should be an integer

Comment: thank you. i thought there is a way to go about it. I've tried labelencoder it doesn't seem to be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to use `pd.factorize`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'userID': ['Louis-RKX', 'Paul-KZ3', 'Alex-98Z', 'Louis-RKX', 'Alex-98Z']})
df['uid'] = pd.factorize(df['userID'])[0]
print(df)

# Output
      userID  uid
0  Louis-RKX    0
1   Paul-KZ3    1
2   Alex-98Z    2
3  Louis-RKX    0
4   Alex-98Z    2
```